# Dependencies in requirements.txt file creates a conflic when using correct version

Tags: python, dependencies, version, dependency-management

When I run my requirements.txt file I get the following error messages

```
ERROR: Cannot install PyJWT==2.0.0 and djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested PyJWT==2.0.0
    djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0 depends on PyJWT<2.0.0 and >=1.5.2
To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

The two dependencies are written like the following:

- PyJWT==2.0.0
- djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0

But what I'm most confused about is the error messages part saying: djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0 depends on PyJWT<2.0.0 and >=1.5.2

Wouldn't the PyJWT version 2.0.0 be good enough?

Comment: ERROR: Cannot install PyJWT==2.0.0 and djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested PyJWT==2.0.0
    djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0 depends on PyJWT<2.0.0 and >=1.5.2

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of conflict is a pain in the ass.
Pip says that the version must be between `PyJWT<2.0.0 and >=1.5.2`, sou you can use the exact `2.0.0`.

Downgrade it to `PyJWT==1.7.1` and it should works!

Comment: I get the following error

ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 53), PyJWT==1.7.1 and djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.0.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested PyJWT==1.7.1
    djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0 depends on PyJWT<2.0.0 and >=1.5.2
    djangorestframework-simplejwt 5.0.0 depends on pyjwt<3 and >=2

Comment: On your requirements.txt, `djangorestframework-simplejwt` is on version `1.11.0` or `5.0.0`? 
Make it `1.11.0`, and PyJWT to `1.7.1` and it should be fine.